# Simple Two-Column Layout with Bootstrap-SASS Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I want a simple two-column layout.  With the code below, the columns are not side by side but instead are following the html default block-level flow.  I am wondering if I am missing some step with installing bootstrap-sass into the rails app.

Relevant Gems in Gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.1.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span8">
                <%= yield %>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <h2> Should be the sideBar</h2>
                <p> 
                    Contain within the second column.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 3 uses different classes for the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Christina above, Bootstrap 3 has different class names for the grid, so class names "span8" and "span4" will not work with Bootstrap 3.  Also mentioned by Christina, the class "row-fluid" needs to be just "row." Here is a quick fix:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <h2> This is the sidebar</h2>
            <p> 
                This is inside the sidebar.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: row-fluid class doesn't exist is Bootstrap 3, it's just .row